# LINQ Query to mimic IS IN

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first

So I have this linq query clause.

```
var ctx = new Context();
IQueryable<Users> consulta = ctx.Users;

if ( filters.Count > 0 )
   query = query.Where( p => filters.Contains(p.Name) || 
                             filters.Contains(p.LastName) );
```

**Filters**

Is an string list that contains unordered names and lastnames (not necessary complete). For example: Filter {Mary, Joseph Ken} but DB {Mary Katie, Joseph Kendall}.

**Expected results**

For the previous filters I want the query to return the list of users no matter if within the filters its names and lastnames are incomplete but correct. So if the filter has "Mary" it must found the db record with "Mary Katie" and so on.

Comment: Your question is uncomplete. Try to understand your own question without knowing any details. What are `query` and `filters` for example? Provide sample data and a desired result.

Comment: If this is linq2entity tag it respectively.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri is Entity Code First.

Comment: So tag it according to your requirement, e.g add linq2entity to your tags, Also you can see my answer, I don't know I got your question truly or not.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I already edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mix of [`String.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) and `Any` to solve your problem in linq2entity without fetching extra data from DB:

```
var ctx = new Context();
IQueryable<Users> consulta = ctx.Users;

if ( filters.Count > 0 )
   query = query.Where( p => filters.Any(x=>x.Contains(p.Name)) || 
                             filters.Any(x=>x.Contains(p.LastName)) ||
                             filters.Any(x=>p.Name.Contains(x)) || 
                             filters.Any(x=>p.LastName.Contains(x)));
```

Comment: It seems not to work. Result set is the same again. Only found the users with name say "Bob Knob" if the filter is "Bob Knob" not "Bob".

Comment: @RandolfRincón-Fadul, See my edit, this should work for you, you can remove extra `Any` calls, actually I don't know your exact DB and filter format and I wrote all possible cases. But it doesn't have significant affect to the performance.

Comment: Thanks @SaeedAmiri, you're the boss! Actually just the two last or do the magic.

Comment: Dude we are here to help each other and enjoying by this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is given a filter

```
Bob
Alice
Jane
```

and items in your query such as

```
Bob Nob
Alice Howzer
Jane Bob
Tim
```

You would get

```
Bob Nob
Alice Howzer
Jane Bob
```

Because the filter matched any part of the first or last name right?

Why not add an extension method to your collection that does something like

```cs
public static bool IsInAny(this IEnumerable<String> source, string name, string delim = " ")
{
    return source.Any(item =>
                          {
                             var splits = name.Split(new[] { delim }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                             return splits.Contains(item);
                          });
}
```

Here is a test you can use to test it

```cs
[Test]
public void TestInAny()
{
    var filters = new[] {"Bob", "Alice"};
    var items = new[] {"Bob Knob", "Alice Jane", "Tim"};

    var found = items.Where(i => filters.IsInAny(i)).ToList();
}
```

Obviously this is just a quick and dirty way and there are cleaner ways of doing it, but at least now you've encapsulated the logic.

Comment: This won't work in linq2entity, and seems OP works with linq2entity.

Comment: Devshorts, thanks for your help but It seems @SaeedAmiri is right.

LINQ to Entities doesn't recognize the method 'Boolean IsInAny(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String], System.String, System.String)' of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along these lines?  I haven't actually tested it out so buyer beware.

```
public static bool IsIn(this string value, IEnumerable<string> compareList)
{
   foreach (string compareValue in compareList)
   {
        if (value.Contains(compareValue))
                return true;
   }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: This is bad way in linq2entity, in fact you should fetch all data and this is devil.

Comment: Didn't notice it was in the context of LinqToEntity.  My bad.  The extension method would have to be translatable to a SQL statement.